# How to change text based on option selected?

Tags: jquery

This is probably simple but I can't work it out.

I want to be able to change some paragraph text based on which option is selected.

HTML

```
<form action="">
<select name="" id="">
  <option id="1" value="One">One</option>
  <option id="2" value="Two">Two</option>
  <option id="3" value="Three">Three</option>
</select>
</form>
<br />
<p>Text</p>
```

JQ

```
$("#1").click(function(){
$("p").html("Changed!");
});
```

Here's the pen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNawgv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't trigger a option element by clicking!
It all have to do with the selector element. You check if an option is selected and the selecet element automatically get the value of the selected option element.

```
<form action="">
<select name="" id="slct">
  <option id="1" value="One">One</option>
  <option id="2" value="Two">Two</option>
  <option id="3" value="Three">Three</option>
</select>
</form>
<br />
<p>Text</p>
```

jQuery

```
$('#slct').change(function(){ // when a option is selected
  //$("p").html($('#slct').val()); // pushs html code in P element
  $("p").text("Changed!");
  /*
    anyway you should use $.text if you don't have HTML element to push in
  */
});
```

Comment: Almost perfetct answer, but if you use a jQuery do it jQuery way: `$("p").text("Changed!");` Anyway +1

Comment: I consider what you said. Thanks for that advise :)

Comment: This sort of works, how to you specifically change the p text?  Is it:`$("p").html($('$slct').value("value"));`

Comment: nope it should be #slct not $slct; and should be like this: https://jsfiddle.net/107evhk1/1/

Comment: That pushes the text/value from the option selected to the paragraph tag?  I was more interested in changing that paragraph text to something custom when an option is selected.

Comment: AH got you. Updated!

Comment: Almost there!  The text needs to change to something different with each different option, so like option 1 - text a, option 2 - text b, option 3 - text c.

Comment: Yeah, there you go you can do these things like you said on your own. IF statements does help you. Trust me. These are just the basics. You just have to do it on your own to be a pro in these things.

Comment: Your welcome :). See that your new on StackOverflow. The community is very big and have almost an answere to your questions :)

Comment: Indeed I am despite having an account for 3 years.  Looking forward to learning more, thank you again I appreciate your assistance.